# How can I run a .js file across multiple accounts in AWS from Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

File is running in the account where the Jenkins node is, its not assuming role into other accounts, not getting any errors.

Comment: how you want to run? thourh ssh or what do you mean running .js file accros account?

Comment: Hi, the file is being run from jenkins under shell command for ex sh """ npm install node script.js """ Now this script.js will run in the node account where the jenkins worker is running, how do I get it to run across multiple accounts in aws?